# Visual Studio Remote Performance Profiling

Tags: visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

I'm attempting to profile a remote process to look at thread and memory diagnostics. When I attempt to attach to the process via Debug, everything works swimmingly. However, when I try to attach through Analyze (for profiling) I cannot find it. Is this functionality not supported at this time?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Windows ADK on remote machine and use Windows Performance Recorder and Windows Performance Analyzer to do some Performance Profiling.